# How to switch views on orientation change

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, optimization, screen-orientation

I'm currently in the midst of creating an application with six views, each view being dedicated to a combination of *device type* and *orientation*. In case you don't understand what I mean, I'll label all six combinations:

- iPhone4_(320x480) & Portrait
- iPhone4_(320x480) & Landscape
- iPhone5_(320x568) & Portrait
- iPhone5_(320x568) & Landscape
- iPad_(768x1024) & Portrait
- iPad_(768x1024) & Landscape

I know it seems a bit silly to go through all of this trouble, but it is kind of required in this situation. Anyway, I've been trying to attempt a combination between Apple's solution from the [Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html) and a method given from an online tutorial found at [TheAppCodeBlog](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/03/30/orientation-change-tutorial-change-the-view-when-the-orientation-changes/).

`ViewController.m` --> `ViewDidLoad` method

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

`ViewController.m` --> `orientationChanged` method

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)object
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[object object] orientation];
    if (deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 480.0)
    {
        self.view = self.portrait4View;
    }
    else if ((deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 480.0)
    {
        self.view = self.landscape4View;
    }
    else if (deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0)
    {
        self.view = self.portrait5View;
    }
    else if ((deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0)
    {
        self.view = self.landscape5View;
    }
    else if (deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 1024.0)
    {
        self.view = self.portraitPadView;
    }
    else
    {
        self.view = self.landscapePadView;
    }

}
```

Interface Builder setup for each view:

[image: Interface Builder]

I'm also receiving a some errors for `Expected identifier`:

[image: Mini Window]

### Update

Whenever I launch the app, I just get a black screen. Here is what my `AppDelegate.m` looks like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_Portrait5" bundle:nil];
    }
    
    else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 480.0) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_Portrait4" bundle:nil];
    }

    else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_PortraitPad" bundle:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error related to `Expected Identifier` is because your parens are wrong.  Your `if` condition should be (and I see the same error in a couple of the other conditions as well):

```
else if (((deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 480.0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now I just feel stupid for not having noticed that. Is there any chance you could help me in my last update I added to the original post as well?

Comment: I see the problem and know the solution to your update.  Please post it as a separate question, and I'll answer it there.  In the meantime, accept the answer to the first question as well please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779342/how-to-launch-specific-views-on-device-type Thanks