# How to Launch Specific Views on Device Type

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, view

I am trying to launch 1 of 3 views on startup. The view I want to launch is depending on the device type. Here is what I have so far in the `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_Portrait5" bundle:nil];
    }

    else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 480.0) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_Portrait4" bundle:nil];
    }

    else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_PortraitPad" bundle:nil];
    }
}
```

The problem is that, when I launch the app, there is a black screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't setting the controller on the window, at the end of the method, add:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: I am now getting a SIGABRT `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ViewController_Portrait5" nib but the view outlet was not set.'`

Comment: Sorry, but please post that as a separate question.  The goal here is to not bundle a bunch of questions into one post...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780016/sigabrt-error-view-outlet-was-not-set Thank you so much for your continuous help. I hope that after all of this, there will be some way I could pay you back.

Answer (score 2):

There's a much cleaner way to write that code (including the fix):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    NSString *nibName;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        nibName = @"ViewController_PortraitPad";
    } else {
        if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 480.0) {
            nibName = @"ViewController_Portrait4";
        } else {
            nibName = @"ViewController_Portrait5";
        }
    }

    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```