# SIGABRT Error "view outlet was not set"

Tags: iphone, view, sigabrt

I'm receiving a SIGABRT error when attempting to run my application on my iPhone 5. My application basically requires 3 views, and depending on which device you're running (iPhone 4, iPhone 5 or iPad), it will launch the view specific to your device type.

The SIGABRT error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ViewController_Portrait5" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

I'm almost positive that the view outlet was set, but I guess I'm wrong.

Here is a screenshot of Xcode window:

[image: Xcode Window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect the "view" outlet.  See how there is an item in that list "view" with no connection?  You need to ensure that every UIViewController is connected to a view.

Since you named the file "portrait" I'm guessing that you'd like the view to be the portrait view, so connected the "view" outlet with the "Portrait" object, under "Objects."

Answer (score 1):

Just drag the little circle next to "view" above your "webView" to the first view.